# Migrating to Xi52

Tags: migration, ibm-datapower

we are planning to migrate our codebase from xI50 to xI52. Could anyone please let me know, how xI52 is different from XI50 ?I am just tryingt to figure out what kind of changes will need to be done to our existing codebase on xI50 to make it compatible on xI52?

Also, I have below two questions:

1) Is Xi52 the best hardware to which we should migrate from Xi50? What are the advantage of Xi52 from others?

2) What are the best practices to migrate the configuration from Xi50 to Xi52?

Regards,
Rahul

Answer (score 2):

Good question Rahul!

As a rule of thumb, the compability of the codebase is essentially an aspect of the running firmware, not the model in itself.

So, figure out the firmware version of your XI50 and your target firmware, which probably is the latest. If you upgrade to the same firmware version (such as version 5), there should be no issues.

Here is a list of all firmwares.
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21237631

The release notes to look for information in each firmware, so go through the list (you may have to aggregate through several firmwares, such as 4.x to 5.x, 5.x to 6.x).

Sometimes, you have to look into individual technotes for info.

In general, DP contains compability rather well, and breaking changes resides mainly in details.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wsdatap/v5r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.dp.xi.doc%2FrelnotesXI.html

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wsdatap/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.dp.xi.doc%2FrelnotesXI.html

Comment: @Petter..Thanks for your answer.We are planning to migrate on Virtual edition of xi52. The work has not bugun as of yet. I will keep this thread open to discuss further on this.

Comment: I rather suggest you mark this question as answered if you think it's complete or detail your question if you want a more specific answer. If you stumble upon specific question within your upcoming project, please open new questions.